# Gmail App, non-google domain sign in

Tags: gmail, google-account, accounts

Suppose I want to add an account and my company/school/organization/etc uses a gmail based solution for their email services.  After telling the gmail app I want to add another account.  My thought would normally be that the sign in should be something like this:

username@company.com
password

But, currently getting a username and password do not match error.  If I attempt to login directly on the gmail.com web page, it redirects me to my company's sign in page and then works.  My guess is the app isn't smart enough to do/handle a redirect to a specific authentication server and thus fails.  Is there some other way I might be able to use gmail?

Comment: You have to add the account in system settings, not the app. When you add a Google Account in Settings, you have the option of hitting the menu key and "Browser Sign-in" to handle the redirects.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add your account as "Personal(POP/IMAP)" and your Mail Server ID has to be 'mail.company.com' and SMTP server as 'smtp.company.com'.

And select the certification accordingly.